# Next Car Game Demo not working

Tags: technical-issues, windows, windows-8, wreckfest

I am trying to get the next car game demo for my computer. After I do everything, the shortcut has not been created and when I try to open up the game, there is an error that says: The program can't start because d3dx9_42.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem. I reinstalled three times and it still has this error upon opening up. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to update DirectX.
[Here's a guide on how to do it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/179113)

Comment: I updated my windows, but it still says the error after I reinstalled it. Is there some other way I can get DirectX?

Comment: There are links to manual DirectX installation files in the link I provided.